# How can i create a NTFS partition on this new HDD?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ntfs

I am having problems creating a new partition on one of my new 6TB HDD. I tried to use GParted and it gave me this .htm error file:

```
GParted 0.25.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2
Create Primary Partition #1 (ntfs, 5.46 TiB) on /dev/sda  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

create empty partition  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
libparted messages    ( INFO )

partition length of 11721041920 sectors exceeds the msdos-partition-table-imposed maximum of 4294967295

========================================
```

It could be pretty nice if you could help me out on this as I am pretty new to ubuntu and don't really know much.

PS I need to create a NTFS partition so  I can install Windows 10   on that drive using a usb media tool.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create that big partitions on an msdos (MBR) disk.

You need to create a new GPT partition table to be able to create a 6TB partition.

You can do it in `gparted` (menu "Device").

Comment: Lol, i can't be more dump than this. Thanks a lot.